# Java Arrays.asList(columnes).contains() return false

Tags: java, android, arraylist

in my application i have `columnes` variable with some data as :

[image]

```
List<String> columnes = getSingleColumn("id");
```

now i'm trying to check single string into this array :

```
Arrays.asList(columnes).contains("1")
```

this check allways return false

My full code:

```
    List<String> columnes = getSingleColumn("id");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        cList = new Categories();
        cList.id = Integer.parseInt(item.getString(SV.FIELD_CATEGORY_ID));
        cList.title = item.getString(SV.FIELD_CATEGORY_TITLE);
        cList.followers = item.getString(SV.FIELD_CATEGORY_FOLLOWERS);
        cList.type = item.getString(SV.FIELD_CATEGORY_TYPE);
        cList.date = item.getString(SV.FIELD_CATEGORY_DATE);
        cList.imageUrl = item.getString(SV.FIELD_CATEGORY_IMAGE_URL);

        Log.e("Check : ", Arrays.asList(columnes).contains(cList.id+""));

} catch (JSONException e) {

}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(columnes)` makes a `List` that contains your list as its sole element.  You probably just should do `columns.contains("1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(list)` returns `List<List<String>>` not `List<String>` so contains method can not find your String in that list of list (From @TAsk's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29861761/991085)).Therefore change

```
Log.e("Check : ", Arrays.asList(columnes).contains(cList.id+""));
```

to

```
Log.e("Check : ", columnes.contains(String.valueOf(cList.id)));
```

and also check value of `cList.id` as

```
Log.e("cList id value: ", String.valueOf(cList.id));
```